# trigger() equivalent in Dart?

Tags: jquery, dart

Is there a jquery's trigger equivalent in dart?

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

or

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "modal-click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "modal-click" );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `element.dispatchEvent()`
I ported some jQuery code to Dart a while ago and had some trouble translating such code because `trigger` had some additional features. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dquery might contain a better replacement.